# mysql function variable set not working

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-function

I am writing a function that should return a floating value.

```
BEGIN


DECLARE due_amount DECIMAL(9,2);
  SET due_amount = (SELECT due_amount FROM (
                SELECT id,  MAX(date), due_amount, user_id
                FROM lunch_transaction
                GROUP BY user_id
                HAVING user_id = user) l);
  IF due_amount IS NULL THEN
    SET due_amount = 0.00;
  END IF;
  RETURN due_amount;
END
```

The function only returns value `0.00` even though the value should be something else.

Running only this query :

```
(SELECT due_amount FROM (
            SELECT id,  MAX(date), due_amount, user_id
            FROM lunch_transaction
            GROUP BY user_id
            HAVING user_id = user) l);
```

is giving the correct output though.

How should I set the query's output to the variable?

Answer (score 0):

It is really bad practice to use variable name that can conflict with column names.  Also, the subquery seems very unnecessary.  I would try something more like this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_due_amount DECIMAL(9,2);

    SELECT v_due_amount := l.due_amount
    FROM lunch_transaction l
    WHERE l.user_id = in_user;  -- I'm guessing `user` is also a parameter

    IF v_due_amount IS NULL THEN
        SET v_due_amount = 0.00;
    END IF;
    RETURN v_due_amount;
END;
```

Your version has an aggregation function in the subquery.  This makes no sense, because `due_amount` is not the argument of an aggregation function.  This logic should perhaps be:

```
    SELECT v_due_amount := SUM(l.due_amount)
    FROM lunch_transaction l
    WHERE l.user_id = in_user;  -- I'm guessing `user` is also a variable
```

Comment: I need to retrieve user's latest records only, and hence the aggregate function.. is it unnecessary?

Comment: @Azima . . . That is the wrong approach.  I would suggest you ask another question about that.  This answers the syntax problem from this question.